# Are quintuple kicks possible in Hackycat?

Tags: hackycat

I've played Hackycat on the iPad for a few hours and have had five cats active many times. However, no matter how tightly grouped I have all five cats, I have never observed a "quintuple" bonus. I consistently produce consecutive "quadruple" bonuses with the five cats.

Has anyone observed, or know if it is possible to get, a quintuple kick bonus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted the developer and he says that quintuple quicks are not possible. Quadruple kicks are the highest bonus.